# IRQHandler variable

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, stm32cubeide

I wrote interrupt handler code here. The purpose of my code is to interrupt when I press the button. However, there is a problem. When the button is pressed, it interrupts and enters the handler, but does not increase the Buttonpress. I see the debugger reads buttonpress++, but after exiting the handler, the code freezes when it comes to the switch. Buttonpress = 1 does not happen. What is the reason of this? Do I need to assign the variable differently when assigning it?

Here is my Code :

```
/* 1 sec is 1600000 */
void delay(volatile uint32_t);

uint32_t ButtonPress = 0;

/* Interrupt Handlers */
void EXTI0_1_IRQHandler(void){

    ButtonPress++;
    EXTI->RPR1 |= (1U << 1);
}



int main(void) {

    uint32_t ButtonPress = 0;

    /* Enable GPIOA clock */
    RCC->IOPENR |= (1U << 0);

    /* Setup PA0 as output */
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~(3U << 2*0);
    GPIOA->MODER |= (1U << 2*0);

    /* Setup PA1 as input */
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~(3U << 2*1);
    GPIOA->MODER |= (0U << 2*1);

    /* External interrupt at PA1 port */
    EXTI->EXTICR[0] |= (0U << 8*1);

    /* Mask and Rising on Px1 */
    EXTI->IMR1  |= (1U << 1);
    EXTI->RTSR1 |= (1U << 1);
    EXTI->FTSR1 |= (1U << 1);

    /* Setup NVIC */
    NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI0_1_IRQn, 0);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_1_IRQn);

    while(1) {

        switch(ButtonPress){

            case 0:
                /* Turn off LED */
                GPIOA->ODR = (0U << 0);
                break;

            case 1:
                /* Turn on LED 2sec interval */
                GPIOA->ODR |= (1U << 0);
                delay(3200000);
                GPIOA->ODR ^= (1U << 0);
                delay(3200000);
                break;

            case 2:
                /* Turn on LED 1sec interval */
                GPIOA->ODR |= (1U << 0);
                delay(1600000);
                GPIOA->ODR ^= (1U << 0);
                delay(1600000);
                break;

            case 3:
                /* Turn on LED 0.5sec interval */
                GPIOA->ODR |= (1U << 0);
                delay(800000);
                GPIOA->ODR ^= (1U << 0);
                delay(800000);
                break;

            case 4:
                /* Turn on LED 0.1sec interval */
                GPIOA->ODR |= (1U << 0);
                delay(160000);
                GPIOA->ODR ^= (1U << 0);
                delay(160000);
                break;

            case 5:
                /* Turn on LED */
                GPIOA->ODR |= (1U << 0);
                break;

            case 6:
                /* Button Clear */
                ButtonPress = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void delay(volatile uint32_t s) {
    for(; s>0; s--);
}
```

`

I wrote interrupt handler code here. The purpose of my code is to interrupt when I press the button. However, there is a problem. When the button is pressed, it interrupts and enters the handler, but does not increase the Buttonpress. I see the debugger reads buttonpress++, but after exiting the handler, the code freezes when it comes to the switch. Buttonpress = 1 does not happen. What is the reason of this? Do I need to assign the variable differently when assigning it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared the `ButtonPress` variable twice: once in the global scope and once in `main`. When the interrupt is called, only the global scope version is in scope and therefore that variable is incremented. When it comes to the `switch` statement in `main` however, the other variable is in (a smaller) scope and so that variable is used instead. To fix this, you could remove the declaration of `ButtonPress` at the beginning of `main`.

Comment: And this global variable should be made `volatile`, because it can change out-of-sight of `main()`. Else the compiler might optimize the switch-case to only `case 0`.

Comment: Exactly ! @frankplow see also my comment to your related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74224278/exticr-interrupt-ports