# EXTICR interrupt ports

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, stm32cubeide

In the code I wrote, I chose the PA1 port as an input and connected a button to this input port, then I wrote an interrupt to this button.

first, I write like this and it didn't work
EXTI->EXTICR[0] |= (0U << 8*1);

then, I wrote like this,
EXTI->EXTICR[0] |= (1U << 8*3);    and it worked.

I am trying to make PA1 to be an input. and A = 0 this is why i want to write 0U and i want to write 8*1 cause of port is Px1.

my code :

```
    /* External interrupt at PA1 port */
    EXTI->EXTICR[0] |= (1U << 8*3);
```

---

But I think it should be like,

```
    /* External interrupt at PA1 port */
    EXTI->EXTICR[0] |= (0U << 8*1);
```

Can you explain, why PA1 input is (1U << 8*3) and not (0U << 8*1)

When I write

```
    /* External interrupt at PA1 port */
    EXTI->EXTICR[0] |= (1U << 8*3);
```

This, the program is working successfully. But I didn't understand why I have to write (1U << 8*3), shouldn't I write (0U << 8*1)?

This is my FULL code :

```
/*
 * project name : 05_EXTIbuttonSM
 * file name    : main.c
 *
 * author       : Cem Furkan Demirkıran
 *
 * date         : 2022.10.27
 *
 * description   : A state machine blink the external LED at different intervals.
 *   Assigned each speed to a mode, and attach a button to cycle through the modes.
 *   Used external interrupts to detect button presses and used the handler to
 *   change the states. Each button press will cycle through these modes.
 */

#include "stm32g0xx.h"

/* 1 Sec is 1600000 */
void delay(volatile uint32_t);

uint32_t ButtonPress = 0;

/* Interrupt Handlers */
void EXTI0_1_IRQHandler(void){

    if (ButtonPress != 5) {
            ButtonPress ++;
        }
        else {
            ButtonPress = 0;
        }
        delay(100000);
        EXTI->RPR1 |= (1U << 1);
}



int main(void) {

    /* Enable GPIOA clock */
    RCC->IOPENR |= (1U << 0);

    /* Setup PA0 as output */
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~(3U << 2*0);
    GPIOA->MODER |= (1U << 2*0);

    /* Setup PA1 as input */
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~(3U << 2*1);
    GPIOA->MODER |= (0U << 2*1);

    /* External interrupt at PA1 port */
    EXTI->EXTICR[0] |= (1U << 8*3);

    /* Mask and Rising on Px1 */
    EXTI->IMR1  |= (1U << 1);
    EXTI->RTSR1 |= (1U << 1);

    /* Setup NVIC */
    NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI0_1_IRQn, 0);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_1_IRQn);

    while(1) {

        switch(ButtonPress){

            case 0:
                /* Turn off LED */
                GPIOA->ODR = (0U << 0);
                break;

            case 1:
                /* Turn on LED 2sec interval */
                GPIOA->ODR |= (1U << 0);
                delay(3200000);
                GPIOA->ODR ^= (1U << 0);
                delay(3200000);
                break;

            case 2:
                /* Turn on LED 1sec interval */
                GPIOA->ODR |= (1U << 0);
                delay(1600000);
                GPIOA->ODR ^= (1U << 0);
                delay(1600000);
                break;

            case 3:
                /* Turn on LED 0.5sec interval */
                GPIOA->ODR |= (1U << 0);
                delay(800000);
                GPIOA->ODR ^= (1U << 0);
                delay(800000);
                break;

            case 4:
                /* Turn on LED 0.1sec interval */
                GPIOA->ODR |= (1U << 0);
                delay(160000);
                GPIOA->ODR ^= (1U << 0);
                delay(160000);
                break;

            case 5:
                /* Turn on LED */
                GPIOA->ODR |= (1U << 0);
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void delay(volatile uint32_t s) {
    for(; s>0; s--);
}
```

This is working code after the Answers.

- Added Volatile
- Changing (1U << 8*3) to (0U << 8*1)
- Also Changing Handler for bouncing problem.

```
/*
 * project name : 05_EXTIbuttonSM
 * file name    : main.c
 *
 * author       : Cem Furkan Demirkıran
 *
 * date         : 2022.10.27
 *
 * description   : A state machine blink the external LED at different intervals.
 *   Assigned each speed to a mode, and attach a button to cycle through the modes.
 *   Used external interrupts to detect button presses and used the handler to
 *   change the states. Each button press will cycle through these modes.
 */

#include "stm32g0xx.h"

/* 1 Sec is 1600000 */
void delay(volatile uint32_t);

volatile uint32_t ButtonPress = 0;

/* Interrupt Handlers */
void EXTI0_1_IRQHandler(void){

    if (ButtonPress != 5) {
            delay(50);
            if(ButtonPress !=5)
                ButtonPress ++;
            else
                ButtonPress = 0;
        }
        else {
            ButtonPress = 0;
        }
        delay(100000);
        EXTI->RPR1 |= (1U << 1);
}



int main(void) {

    /* Enable GPIOA clock */
    RCC->IOPENR |= (1U << 0);

    /* Setup PA0 as output */
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~(3U << 2*0);
    GPIOA->MODER |= (1U << 2*0);

    /* Setup PA1 as input */
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~(3U << 2*1);
    GPIOA->MODER |= (0U << 2*1);

    /* External interrupt at PA1 port */
    EXTI->EXTICR[0] |= (0U << 8*1);

    /* Mask and Rising on Px1 */
    EXTI->IMR1  |= (1U << 1);
    EXTI->RTSR1 |= (1U << 1);

    /* Setup NVIC */
    NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI0_1_IRQn, 0);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_1_IRQn);

    while(1) {

        switch(ButtonPress){

            case 0:
                /* Turn off LED */
                GPIOA->ODR = (0U << 0);
                break;

            case 1:
                /* Turn on LED 2sec interval */
                GPIOA->ODR |= (1U << 0);
                delay(3200000);
                GPIOA->ODR ^= (1U << 0);
                delay(3200000);
                break;

            case 2:
                /* Turn on LED 1sec interval */
                GPIOA->ODR |= (1U << 0);
                delay(1600000);
                GPIOA->ODR ^= (1U << 0);
                delay(1600000);
                break;

            case 3:
                /* Turn on LED 0.5sec interval */
                GPIOA->ODR |= (1U << 0);
                delay(800000);
                GPIOA->ODR ^= (1U << 0);
                delay(800000);
                break;

            case 4:
                /* Turn on LED 0.1sec interval */
                GPIOA->ODR |= (1U << 0);
                delay(160000);
                GPIOA->ODR ^= (1U << 0);
                delay(160000);
                break;

            case 5:
                /* Turn on LED */
                GPIOA->ODR |= (1U << 0);
                break;

        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void delay(volatile uint32_t s) {
    for(; s>0; s--);
}
```

Comment: Which micro controller is this? At least the family... and at best link the datasheet.

Comment: `(0U << 8*1)` what do you expect is going to change ORing with zeros?

Comment: It would also benefical if you posted what `EXTI->EXTICR` is and how it is defined.

Comment: M0+ board is g031k8.

Comment: EXTI is Interrupt. I have input the PA1 port in the code and I want to assign an interrupt to it.

(1U << 8*3)
What I don't understand is where the 3 here comes from.

Comment: Why we bitwise 3 times ? its port Px1 not Px3

Comment: Your calculation of values 8, 1 and 0 are all correct.  The problem is certainly somewhere else.

Comment: I added my full code. it is working like that.

Comment: BTW You should use ‘volatile uint32_t ButtonPress = 0;’. Variables shared by ISR and application code have to be volatile. Otherwise you might encounter surprises when using the optimizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, 8 means the number of bits per bitfield, and 3 or 1 is the number of whole bitfields you want to skip.  The 0 or 1 on the left is the value you put in the bitfield.

I would advise you to use named constants here rather than magic numbers, to make the code easier to read.

If you do:

```
EXTI->EXTICR[0] |= (1U << 8*3);
```

This means skip 3 fields each of 8 bits and put the value 1 in the fourth field.  This sets up an interrupt on PB3.

```
EXTI->EXTICR[0] |= (0U << 8*1);
```

This means skip 1 field of 8 bits and put the value 0 in the second field.  This sets up an interrupt on PA1.

Note also that using `|=` you are only setting bits.  If the peripheral is in its default reset state of having the register at all zeros then this is fine, but if you have already written to the field you want to change then you may also need to clear some bits with `&` and '~' too.

Comment: ORRing something with zero doesn't change it. It's a NO-OP. The compiler probably doesn't even generate code for x |= (0 << 8).

Comment: It is still good practice to write code that puts zeros in bit fields that you want to be zero so that the person who reads the code knows that you are intentionally setting (or in this case leaving) it to that value.  If you try to do the job of the optimizer in your head rather than properly letting the toolchain do its for you then when you come to edit this code you have to get the register manual out again, whereas if you had written the zero explicitly you could just see which value you want to change.

Comment: Except that this code does not put zeros anywhere. To put zero you mask with an AND operation and all ones except zeros where you want zeros.

Comment: It puts a zero in the line of source code.  The point I am trying to teach you is that making the source code show your intention is more important than penny pinching instructions.  The fact that that the default value of this register is already the one that is wanted in this case is irrelevant.  Making the source code clearer is worth having the two unnecessary  instructions this will put in the binary.

Comment: @TomV I think it would be clearer if you removed the suggestion that the ORR "puts a value zero in a field", and add the correct foo &= ~(1 << 8) to clear it.

Comment: @TomV I'm also a bit confused why setting a bit enables an interrupt on PB3 but clearing a bit enables an interrupt on PA1. I guess it might work like that but seems unlikely.

Comment: The fields are 8 bits each, to clear the second one you need `~(0xFFu << 8)`.

Comment: In the usual case when the register starts from its reset state, then the code that the OP provided writes a 0 to the field of the register, which maps the pin 1 interrupt to bank A (for bank B write 1, etc). It is true that it only works if the register was already at zero, but reading a 0 and writing a 0 is harmless and having it there makes the code more maintainable because when you change the pinout you only have to change a single digit. It would be better if rather than a digit it was a named constant, but the question was to explain the reason for the values not improve the code style.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249122/discussion-between-tom-v-and-pmacfarlane).